# Search for an element in D3 - force layout or tree

Tags: d3.js, tree, highlight, force-layout

Is there an example of searching for an element in a d3js layout (force directed or tree) and highlighting that element?

I am thinking that there would be a text field where user enters values to search.

Comment: how add search to force layout ? plz chek this [Search an Element in D3 Force Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576985/search-an-element-in-d3-force-layout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a tool that allows browsing biological [regulatory networks](http://www.regulatorynetworks.org), showing two SVG panels side-by-side. Each panel contains a force-layout network of transcription factors (the nodes), as drawn by the d3.js API. You can type in the name of a transcription factor and it will highlight it using the same code as is used when a `mouseover` event occurs. Exploring the code might give you some insight into how it's done.

Comment: this is a nice demo, have you dove into the creation process anywhere? Perhaps a blog or something?

Comment: Your code throws some errors in the console . you might want to take a look at it

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [gist](http://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950) I made, perhaps relevant?

I broke my implementation into 3 steps:

1) On selection of a leaf node name in the select2 box, searchTree.

```
$("#search").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
    var paths = searchTree(root,e.object.text,[]);
    if(typeof(paths) !== "undefined"){
        openPaths(paths);
    }
    else{
        alert(e.object.text+" not found!");
    }
})
```

2) searchTree returns an array of nodes in order of distance from the root node (the path)

```
function searchTree(obj,search,path){
    if(obj.name === search){ //if search is found return, add the object to the path and return it
        path.push(obj);
        return path;
    }
    else if(obj.children || obj._children){ //if children are collapsed d3 object will have them instantiated as _children
       var children = (obj.children) ? obj.children : obj._children;
       for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
            path.push(obj);// we assume this path is the right one
            var found = searchTree(children[i],search,path);
            if(found){// we were right, this should return the bubbled-up path from the first if statement
                return found;
            }
            else{//we were wrong, remove this parent from the path and continue iterating
                path.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    else{//not the right object, return false so it will continue to iterate in the loop
        return false;
    }
}
```

3) open the path by replacing "._children" with ".children" and add the class "found" to color everything red. (see link and node instantiations)

```
function openPaths(paths){
    for(var i=0;i<paths.length;i++){
        if(paths[i].id !== "1"){//i.e. not root
            paths[i].class = 'found';
            if(paths[i]._children){ //if children are hidden: open them, otherwise: don't do anything
                paths[i].children = paths[i]._children;
                paths[i]._children = null;
            }
            update(paths[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

I realize this may not be the most optimal way to do this but hey, gets the job done :)

Comment: Thank for you for having shared your code.

 It seems that the searchTree function does not find multiple results, when you have the same name in 2 different nodes.

 Is there easier solution as mentionned others based on selectAll ?

Answer (score 5):

I have coded a solution with a search widget based on a select2.
You get found nodes with their paths expanded styled in red.
The tree is fully explored and multiple answers can be found.

**Collapsible Tree Search**
https://gist.github.com/PBrockmann/0f22818096428b12ea23

Hope that will help
Patrick

Comment: When I search for a node in the drop-down, duplicate values are [displayed](http://i.imgur.com/3dAlJ1R.jpg) - why is that ?

Comment: nevermind, i found the problem. Around line 205 of your code, the - select2Data.sort(function(a, b) - code is repeated. I removed one of them and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you asking for a d3.selectAll ?

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_selectAll

1. Use an text field with a search button.
2. Translate the search into a D3/CSS3 selector in your nodes.
3. d3.selectAll
4. Apply new styles to the nodes that match / don't make  your query.

Comment: Is there any simple example?  I am new to both d3 and javascript.  Thanks anyway. I think I can work it out.

Comment: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html Just do a selectall like this "vis.selectAll("circle.node")", but except for looking for a circle with the class "node", change the criteria to whatever you like. This is the selection reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors, where "circle.node" is the "E.warning" row (e.g., class selector)