# Search an Element in D3 Force Layout

Tags: d3.js

Base on [Collapsible Tree Search](https://gist.github.com/PBrockmann/0f22818096428b12ea23), I was able to search an element using the force directed graph. The problem is when I choose a search name, it will only hightlight the element and  its first level of parent. How to hightlight the links and the nodes from the search element to the root?

Here's my code on Plunker [Search on Force Directed Graph](http://plnkr.co/edit/cyBKL3frDaV648gn9uO9).

```
function searchTree (d) {
    if (d.children)
        d.children.forEach(searchTree);
    else if (d._children)
        d._children.forEach(searchTree);
    var searchFieldValue = eval(searchField);   
    if (searchFieldValue && searchFieldValue.match(searchText)) {
            // Walk parent chain
            var ancestors = [];
            var parent = d;
            while (typeof(parent) !== "undefined") {
                ancestors.push(parent);
      //    console.log(parent);
                parent.class = "found";
                parent = parent.parent;
            }
     //  console.log(ancestors);
    }
}
```

I've already compared everything on how it was being implemented on a tree but I was not able to find it out why.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: The question is how to highlight the links and nodes from the search element to the root?

Comment: There's no notion of a root in the force layout. You could designate an arbitrary node the root node and then on search find the path from the found node to the "root".

Comment: Thanks for the response @LarsKotthoff . I will try that one.

Comment: Did you find the solution? If so, please post it.